# Variable not changing from null

Tags: android, android-edittext

my program is suposes to change bname to position but won't for some reason 
I send position to Record Expeance this waycase 
R.id.record_expeance:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(BudgetStart.this, RecordExpeance.class));
    ex.changeName(position);
    BudgetStart.this.finish();
    break;
```

after that is should be equal to position but it remains null I'm not sure if this is cause I start that class new or something but I can't figure it out

```
package budget.app;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RecordExpeance extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{    
    private String bname;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recordexpeance);
        final BudgetDB entry = new BudgetDB(RecordExpeance.this);
        EditText a =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtExpeance);
        EditText b =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEMomo);
        TextView c =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblBudgetAmount);
        TextView d =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblBudgetName);
       d.setText(bname);

        String bamount;

        entry.open();
        bamount = entry.getBamount(bname);
        entry.close();

        Button A = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);

        A.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View argo) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(RecordExpeance.this, BudgetStart.class));
        RecordExpeance.this.finish();
    }
    public void changeName(String position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        bname = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do what you're trying to do. `R.id.record_expeance` only exists in the layout you have loaded in the first activity.  Even if you create a textview with the same id in the second activity layout, it will be a *different* textview.  The id is only an index to the view in the currently loaded layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to pass `position` in the Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BudgetStart.this, RecordExpeance.class);
intent.putExtra("position", position);
startActivity(intent);
BudgetStart.this.finish();
break;
```

Then read it from the Intent in `RecordExpeance`:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.recordexpeance);

bname = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 1); 
// Where 1 is the default value if you forgot use putExtra()
```

Comment: easier, and better in every other way.

Comment: @Sam thank you for your help when i tried this at frist it didnt work but u got me going on the right track thank you ver much.